# CD Drive doesn't recognize inserted CD/DVD in disc drive in UBUNTU 16.04 LTS

Tags: mount, dvd, filemanager, ubuntu-drivers, cd-drive

I'm a new Ubuntu user. I wanted to make a live CD for an OS change in another computer. 
When i insert a CD or DVD in the disc drive, the Drive will start spinning but it will not show the mounted disc. I can't find it on the file manager. The disks also wont show any Inserted Disc. I haven't tried any command lines yet.
I can't decide if its my drives fault because it worked well before i switched to Ubuntu.
[Disks Application wont recognize inserted CD/DVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAans.png)

Comment: Is the CD empty or does it already contain something? Empty disks won't show up as mounted devices.

Comment: @PerlDuck I tried  a blank at first but didnt show. Then i tried a loaded disc but it doesnt show either.